# mysql exists or not exists select query

Tags: mysql

```
Table A
ID | date
 1 | 2014-05-16
 2 | 2014-05-15
 3 | 2014-05-16
 4 | 2014-05-17
 5 | 2014-05-18

 Table B
 ID| A.ID   | B.Key | B.KeyValue
 1 | 1      | date  | 2014-07-23
 2 | 3      | date  | 2014-07-11
 3 | 4      | date  | 2013-10-07
```

Let's say I have two tables, A & B. How do I come up with all of A, but have linked records in B replace the 'date' in A. eg.:

A.1 links up with B.1, and so the new date in A should be 2014-07-23 and not 2014-05-16.

Also, I'd like to have it sorted by the new date. e.g.,

```
1 | 2014-07-23
3 | 2014-07-11
5 | 2014-05-18
2 | 2014-05-15
4 | 2013-10-07
```

So far, I have this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT A.ID, 
    IF(B.Key = 'date', IF(B.KeyValue <> '', B.KeyValue, A.date), A.date) new_date
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
ORDER BY new_date DESC
```

But some how I come up with duplicates for the linked rows.

Comment: should i be using a different approach? eg, perhaps find all those in A that match in B, then UNION ALL with those in A that don't match?  what i've found is as long as B.Key is written explicitly in the WHERE clause, it will only find 3 rows instead of 5

Comment: try running my query, i just updated it to coincide with your requirements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all you want is to show the data in most recent order after putting in the date from b try this. [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efcb4/2) to play with

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, 
    COALESCE(b_date, a_date) AS updated_date
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
    AND b.key = 'date'
ORDER BY updated_date DESC
```

Comment: it works but also returns other rows from B; hence why there's a B.Key and B.KeyValue

Comment: ok well then i need some data that will be relevant to it showing up... from what I have to work with it works perfectly.

Comment: just insert another row into B with a value other than date for B.Key. eg, 'page' and B.KeyValue= 865

Comment: try it again i added another condition to join off of.

Comment: also if you added that to the sql fiddle then i need the new link to the fiddle to see it :)

Comment: @Nick Yea you needed to not filter all rows in a where for the query, but just left join those that have a date.. and also join off of b.a_id :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the rules here in stackoverflow but while trying to answer this question I tried to run these queries in 2 ways which got varying results and was wondering if someone could explain whats going here

I added one record to the b table so my tables look like this

Table A

```
ID | date
 1 | 2014-05-16
 2 | 2014-05-15
 3 | 2014-05-16
 4 | 2014-05-17
 5 | 2014-05-18
```

Table B

```
ID| A.ID   | B.Key | B.KeyValue
1 | 1      | date  | 2014-07-23
2 | 3      | date  | 2014-07-11
3 | 4      | date  | 2013-10-07
4 | 2      | rnd  | 1999-12-31
```

I ran this query

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, 
    COALESCE(b_date, a_date) AS updated_date
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id and b.key = 'date'
ORDER BY updated_date DESC
```

and this one

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, 
    COALESCE(b_date, a_date) AS updated_date
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id where b.key = 'date'
ORDER BY updated_date DESC
```

The difference is one has

```
and b.key = 'date'
```

the other has

```
where b.key = 'date'
```

Would someone be so kind as to explain what is going on here and why these 2 quires return different results?